# why is map tiling computationally intensive?

Tags: gdal, kml, tiles, superoverlay

I recently starting using `gdal2tiles.py` (and its [parallel implementation](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4379)) to generate tiled images from raster datasets for kml interpretation and I'm shocked by how computationally intensive the process is. For example, rendering a 3.8MB PNG image of the US (35000 x 15000 px - or 2500 dpi @ 14" x 6") with tile levels 0-7 takes over an hour on a modern quad-core system. Even then, the resolution isn't all that great!

What is happening during the tiling process that is so computationally intensive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, that's 525 mega-pixels uncompressed, so the 3.8MB number isn't very useful in thinking about the complexity. All these pixels have to be re-sampled to generate the different tile levels. It's a lot of work. It's also incredibly I/O intensive, so it doesn't matter how many cores you have unless you also have a lot of disks with separate controllers. Oh, and then you have to compress all those tiles back down to the small size we all want.

Comment: +1 as 525,000,000 pixels uncompressed is approximately 1.5GB of data assuming 8bit PNG with 3 bands and no alpha channel.

Comment: I accept that the compression/decompression process makes it quite difficult. However my disk monitoring doesn't suggest that its incredibly I/O intensive. In any case, I gather that uncompressed input data is probably better to use, right?